# jQuery startswith selector

Tags: jquery

```
function test() {
    var foo = [];
    $('#tree table').each(function(i, table) {
        foo[i] = $(table).text().trim();
    });

    var ch = 'G';

    for (j = 0; j <= 12; j++) {
        if (foo[j] ^= ch) {
            alert(foo[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

`[foo[j] ^= ch]`  startsWith selector isn't working in the above code. What do I have to do to get the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `starts-with` selector is for use within jQuery selectors when selecting DOM elements based on the value of an attribute.

This does not work within regular javascript `if()` statements.

Try this instead:

```
var ch = 'G';
if ( foo[j].indexOf(ch) === 0 ) {
    alert( foo[j] );
}
```

This will check `foo[j]` to see if the index position (if any) of the value of the `ch` variable is position `0` (in other words, at the beginning).

---

**EDIT:**

Another alternative would be to specifically test the first character against `ch`. But this will *only* work for testing *one* character. If `ch` contains more than one, it will fail.

```
var ch = 'G';
if ( foo[j].charAt( 0 ) === ch ) {
    alert( foo[j] );
}
```

Comment: @Bala - If this answer was helpful, please remember to "Accept" it by clicking the large checkmark to the left of it. Thanks. :o)

Comment: @ patrick dw - i am new here.And yes, i accepted it now. Thanks.